# "Dodge" overlapping points in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I want to plot a hundred or so points on a world map. Some of the points are too close together, so I would like to be able to separate them, so that they are still approximately in the correct position, but not overlapping the neighbouring points.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158438/spread-overlapping-points-in-a-circle-r) might be useful in some cases, but in others it's going to make previously non-overlapping neighbours overlap.

Is there a nice way to do this in matplotlib, or will I have to manually code some kind of force-sprung separator before plotting?

Comment: Maybe answers to this question can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671808/matplotlib-avoiding-overlapping-datapoints-in-a-scatter-dot-beeswarm-plot

Comment: To make it short, there is no built-in feature that spreads points in matplotlib.  Writing your own algorithm that does it, or looking for similar problems online is necessary. The more of your efforts in finding a solution (either through writing code or through sharing your research) you show the higher the chances someone jumps in and provides help on the issue.

Comment: @Shaido: I don't want jitter. I want something deterministic, so that if e.g A and B are overlapping, they move away from their midpoint an equal distance. If three points are overlapping, they also move away from their midpoint proportionally to the amount of overlap, etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Yes, I know. I'm just aware of e.g. `position_dodge` in ggplot2, which does this, but only in one dimension, and I was wondering if there was something that already existed that I wasn't aware of.