# Add jitterred points to a ggnetwork plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter, ggnetwork

I have a `graph` of vertices and edges which I'd like to plot using a `fruchtermanreingold` layout.

Here's the `graph` edges matrix:

```
edge.mat <- matrix(as.numeric(strsplit("3651,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,11,2,0,0,0,300,0,1,0,0,66,0,78,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,11690,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,493,1,1,0,4288,5,0,0,36,0,9,7,3,0,6,1,0,1,7,490,0,0,0,6,0,0,628,6,12,0,0,0,0,0,641,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,66,0,0,0,0,3165,0,281,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,1,0,0,35248,0,1698,2,0,1,0,2,99,0,0,6,29,286,0,31987,0,1,10,0,8,0,16,0,21,1,0,0,1718,0,51234,0,0,17,3,12,0,0,7,0,0,0,1,0,2,16736,0,0,0,3,0,0,4,630,0,0,0,9,0,0,29495,53,6,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,3,0,19,186,0,0,0,482,8,12,0,1,0,7,1,0,6,0,26338",
                              split = ",")[[1]]),
                   nrow = 14,
                   dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:14], LETTERS[1:14]))
```

I then create an `igraph` object from that using:

```
gr <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(edge.mat, mode="undirected", weighted=T, diag=F)
```

And then use `ggnetwork` to convert `gr` to a `data.frame`, with specified vertex colors:

```
set.seed(1)
gr.df <- ggnetwork::ggnetwork(gr,
                              layout="fruchtermanreingold", 
                              weights="weight", 
                              niter=50000, 
                              arrow.gap=0)
```

And then I plot it using `ggplot2` and `ggnetwork`:

```
vertex.colors <- strsplit("#00BE6B,#DC2D00,#F57962,#EE8044,#A6A400,#62B200,#FF6C91,#F77769,#EA8332,#DA8E00,#C59900,#00ACFC,#C49A00,#DC8D00",
                          split=",")[[1]]

library(ggplot2)
library(ggnetwork)

ggplot(gr.df, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges(color = "gray", aes(size = weight)) +
  geom_nodes(color = "black")+
  geom_nodelabel(aes(label = vertex.names),
                 color = vertex.colors, fontface = "bold")+
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text=element_blank(), 
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none")
```

[image]

In my case each vertex actually represents many points, where each vertex has a different number of points. Adding that information to `gr.df`:

```
gr.df$n <- NA
gr.df$n[which(is.na(gr.df$weight))] <- as.integer(runif(length(which(is.na(gr.df$weight))), 100, 500))
```

What I'd like to do is add to the plot `gr.df$n` radially jittered points around each vertex (i.e., with its corresponding `n`), with the same `vertex.colors` coding. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Im a bit unsure what you want... is this along the right lines `gr_new <- gr.df ; gr_new$n <- 1 ; gr_new$n[which(is.na(gr_new$weight))] <- as.integer(runif(length(which(is.na(gr_new$weight))), 100, 500)) ;
gr_new <- gr_new[rep(rownames(gr_new), gr_new$n),] ;
p + geom_jitter(data=gr_new, aes(x = x, y = y, color = setNames(vertex.colors, levels(gr.df$vertex.names))[gr_new$vertex.names]),  height=0.03, width=0.03, alpha=0.03)` , where `p` is your graph

Comment: Yes, that's close. Only problem is that `geom_jitter` doesn;t spread the points radially, so they end up forming a square rather than a circle. When I try to create `gr_new` where I replace `x` and `y` with radially jittered points (adapted this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158438/spread-overlapping-points-in-a-circle-r), and use `geom_point` I get something weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think sampling and then plotting with `geom_point` is a reasonable strategy. (otherwise you could create your own geom).

Here is some *rough* code, starting from the relevant bit of your question

```
gr.df$n <- 1
gr.df$n[which(is.na(gr.df$weight))] <- as.integer(runif(length(which(is.na(gr.df$weight))), 100, 500))

# function to sample
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly
circSamp <- function(x, y, R=0.1){
    n <- length(x)
    A <- a <- runif(n,0,1)
    b <- runif(n,0,1)

    ind <- b < a
    a[ind] <- b[ind]
    b[ind] <- A[ind]

    xn = x+b*R*cos(2*pi*a/b)
    yn = y+b*R*sin(2*pi*a/b)
    cbind(x=xn, y=yn)
 }


# sample  
d <- with(gr.df, data.frame(vertex.names=rep(vertex.names, n),
                            circSamp(rep(x,n), rep(y,n))))

# p is your plot   
p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x, y, color = vertex.names),
               alpha=0.1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
    scale_color_manual(values = vertex.colors)
```

Giving

[image]